# Java: How to open JOptionPane from a JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, joptionpane, messagebox, jgrasp

I have a program which has many JButtons which opens jframes, I want my help button to open a JoptionPane message box, but everytime I click on the help button nothing happens.

```
//Main Menu

import javax.swing.*;
// Create Main Menu page

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt. *;
import java.io.*;


   public class mainMenu implements ActionListener     // create new class mainMenu
{
    JFrame Start=new JFrame("Main Menu");             // name frame Main Menu
    JButton Search ;
    JButton Create;      // create new buttons
    JButton Delete;
    JButton Help;
 {
      Search=new JButton("Search for Existing Contact"); 
      Create=new JButton("Create a New Contact");           // set name of all buttons
      Delete=new JButton("Delete a Contact");
      Help=new JButton("Help");
      Search.setActionCommand("Search");
      Create.setActionCommand("Create");
      Delete.setActionCommand("Delete");
      Help.setActionCommand("Help");
      Start.setSize(510,600);       // set size of frame
      Start.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("mainMenuBG.jpg")));   // add background 
      Start.setVisible(true);
      Start.setLayout(null);
      Start.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      Start.getContentPane().add(Search);
      Start.getContentPane().add(Create);     // add buttons to frame
      Start.getContentPane().add(Delete);
      Start.getContentPane().add(Help);  
      Search.setBounds(100,25,295,88);
      Create.setBounds(100,150,295,88);        // set size of buttons
      Delete.setBounds(100,275,295,88);
      Help.setBounds(100,400,295,88);
      Search.addActionListener(this);
      Create.addActionListener(this);   
      Delete.addActionListener(this);
      Help.addActionListener(this);

 }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String command = e.getActionCommand();
     if ("Search".equals(command)) {
      Start.dispose();
      LTS B=new LTS();
  }    
     else if ("Create".equals(command)) {
      Start.dispose();
      LTS B=new LTS();
  }
     else if ("Delete".equals(command)) {
      Start.dispose();
      LTS B=new LTS();
  }
     else if ("Help".equals(command)) {
      helpPage2 B=new helpPage2();
  }
}

   public static void main(String ag[])
  {
      mainMenu B=new mainMenu();
  }


}
```

The helpPage2 should open the message box

```
// Help Page 2

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class helpPage2 {  // Create a new class helpPage

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELPPPPP PAGEE","Help", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // Create Information Message 
    }
}
```

Not sure What I am Missing, some guidance would be greatly appreciated, also the other buttons work, just the helpPage2 does not. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this,

```
 if ("Help".equals(command)) {
//  helpPage2 B=new helpPage2();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELPPPPP PAGEE","Help", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // Create Information Message  
}
```

with in the method you can call dialog box.

let me if you have any quires.

Comment: OH i see, so this way I won't even need to create a new class. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: yeah. you no need to create new class for JOptionPane. 
Note: if you want to create customize JOptionPane that time only you need to create.

Comment: Thank You so much. New to java this website is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a constructor in helpPage2 instead of a main method

Comment: a constructor would be "public helpPage2 () {...code...}" it is called when the class is initialized

Comment: Thanks for helping, someone else had a really easy solution to this though.

Comment: I didn't know if you wanted to add other stuff in that class, so I tried to stay as open as possible.

Comment: Oh, I was just trying to get the message box to open, well I will keep in mind what you told me for future use. Thanks.